# Surface element for sphere, can't find what's wrong

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that surface element for any surface is:

$$dS=\sqrt{ 1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 }dxdy$$

Say if we want to find a surface element of the sphere of radius r, $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ it gives us:

$$dS=\frac{r}{z}dxdy$$

In spherical coordinates:
$dxdy=r^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$ and $z=r\cos(\theta)$

It becomes: $$dS=r^2 \tan(\theta) d\theta d\phi$$

Which clearly diverges integrating $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi/2$.

I can't figure out what is my mistake.

EDIT: The problem was that I got $dxdy$ wrong. It suppose to be: $$dxdy=r^2sin\theta cos\theta d\theta d\phi$$
Thank you for the help **Brady Trainor** and **achille hui**

Comment: how do you get your $dxdy$ element?

Comment: $dxdy$ element in spherical coordinates could be computed using Jacobian determinant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: I'll use that to think out loud below.

Comment: I think the surface element at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral would be more appropriate. Not sure exactly how you want to use the Jacobian?

Comment: Your $dxdy$ is wrong, should be $r^2\sin\theta d\sin\theta d\phi = r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta d\phi$.

Comment: achille hui, how did you came up with it?

Comment: 1) use polar coordinate, $dx dy = \rho d\rho d\phi$ and $\rho = r\sin\theta$. or 2) directly compute it. $$\begin{align}dx \wedge dy = & d(r\sin\theta \cos\phi) \wedge d(r\sin\theta\sin\phi)\\ = & r^2 ( \cos\theta\cos\phi d\theta - \sin\theta\sin\phi d\phi ) \wedge ( \cos\theta\sin\phi d\theta + \sin\theta\cos\phi d\phi )\\ = & r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta (\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi ) d\theta \wedge d\phi\\ = & r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta d\theta \wedge d\phi\end{align}$$ The use of wedge product here is equivalent to the use of Jacobian.

Comment: did $\rho r$ become $r^2$? Also, isn't $d\rho=0$?

Comment: never mind, had them flipped

Comment: $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the radius of the projection of (x,y,z) on the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking out loud here:

\begin{align*}
x&=r\sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
y&=r\sin\theta\sin\phi,\\
z&=r\cos \theta.
\end{align*}

$$dxdy=dx\times dy
=r^2\begin{vmatrix}
\hat r&\hat\theta&\hat\phi\\
0&\cos\theta\cos\phi\, d\theta&-\sin\theta\sin\phi\, d\phi\\
0&\cos\theta\cos\phi\, d\theta&\sin\theta\cos\phi\, d\phi
\end{vmatrix}=r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\, d\phi.$$

I dropped an $\hat r$ at the end. Compare to wiki article on surface integrals for instance.

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding what kind of determinant is this? I find this to be ambiguous, because you guys say that $dxdy=r^2sin\theta cos\theta d\theta d\phi$ and wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Further_examples) says that $dxdy=J(\theta, \phi)d\theta d\phi$ where Jacobian $J(\theta, \phi)=r^2sin(\theta)$. I seem to be mixing something.

Comment: That's for a volume element, if you read carefully, it's $dxdydz=J(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi$.

Comment: It's more of a cross-product than a determinant.

Comment: Then again, I guess you can use the Jacobian approach. Try applying the Jacobian to $(x(\theta,\phi),y(\theta,\phi))$. You should get the same as we got.

Comment: (Notice it's just the upper right $2\times2$-submatrix of $J_F$ at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Further_examples)

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understand where my confusion arose from. For some reason I thought that I can use the same Jacobian for surface and volume element transformations.